# How to call a datetime in a new operator

Tags: c#

How to call the datetime from the public person method. I have tried in the main method to do it with a yyyy. What I need is a birthdate to be displayed for this particular person.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public Person(string fn, string mn, string ln, DateTime dob)
    {
            FirstName = fn;
            MiddleName = mn;
            LastName = ln; 
            DateOfBirth = dob;
    }
    //Other properties, methods, events...
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Person person1 = new Person("Leopold", "", "Hyggesen", yyyy);
        Console.WriteLine("person1 First name = {0} Middle name = {1} Last name = {2} Date of birth = {3}", person1.FirstName, person1.MiddleName, person1.LastName, person1.DateOfBirth);
```

Comment: Look at the docs for the DateTime constructor https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What date/time do you expect `yyyy` to be?  Did you try `new DateTime()`?

Comment: What is a `yyyy`? If that is a `DateTime` variable it should work, but i don't see it's declaration

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Person person1 = new Person("Leopold", "", "Hyggesen", new DateTime(2016,1,1));
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked.. But now there is a clock stamp as well (00:00:00) Would it be possible only to display the date and not the clock?

Comment: @Aafflalo Use `ToString` with the [format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) that you want.

Comment: Try DateTime.ToShortDateTime() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry, it's person1.DateOfBirth.ToShortDateString(), which will output the date only in the current culture.